# what's the best way to handle concurrency issues when modifying excel files using ADO.NET?

Tags: excel, concurrency, ado.net

I know that Excel files should not be treated like databases, but assuming that you are stuck having to use ADO.NET to add data to excel files which could be modified at any time by any user, what's the best way to handle concurrency issues?

to be more specific, how do I place a lock on the excel file before ADO.NET makes an attempt to update the file without having that lock prevent ADO.NET from making updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your lock on a totally separate file, created for that purpose.  It's an ugly solution, but so is having to modify Excel files with ADO.NET.